# How to prevent CalloutAnnotation from overlapping

Tags: c#, charts, annotations

I am fairly new to annotations, I have placed a line and callout annotation in a chart (as below), how can I prevent the callout annotations from overlapping (as indicated in the blue circle)?

[annotated chart http://cm.heavenskincare.com/chart.png](http://cm.heavenskincare.com/chart.png)

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4.0 and later, use the `SmartLabelStyle` property, like this:

```
annotation.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
```

Read [Annotation.SmartLabelStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotation.smartlabelstyle.aspx) for more information.